# React native how to make an image take up full screen?

Tags: react-native

I have a component that when called should display an image for the whole screen of the phone. The issue is I cannot get the image centered. It is mostly off screen to the right with some barely visible. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong your help would be much appreciated. I am using react-native-image-zoom so the image can be zoomed on and swiped down to go away.

My image component:

```
const FullPicture = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
      <ImageZoom
        cropWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
        cropHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height}
        enableSwipeDown
        onSwipeDown={() => props.closeImage()}
      >
        <Image
          style={{ height: props.picture.height, width: props.picture.width }}
          resizeMode={'cover'}
          source={{ uri: props.picture.uri }}
        />
      </ImageZoom>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [Flexbox](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#proptypes). Try to add `flex: 1` to your Image's container:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
  <ImageZoom> ... </ImageZoom>
</View>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I am calling this component inside of a modal not sure if that would affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

- set `flex: 1` in your container view
- use `justifyContent: 'center'`

check [this](https://medium.com/@shanerudolfworktive/7-tips-to-develop-react-native-uis-for-all-screen-sizes-7ec5271be25c) out.

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I am calling this component inside of a modal not sure if that would affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the thing what you are looking for https://youtu.be/YRrji3BmHY4
you should use ImageBackground from react-native instead of react-native-image-zoom.

when you use ImageBackground don't forget resizeMode='contain' and styling the image, the image will not get off by any side.